# How can I search with a boolean filter on elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I tried follow the elasticsearch doc to execute my elasticsearch with a filter but couldn't do that.
Here is my example:

```
class Post
  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    self.as_json(
      only: [ :id, :title, :published ],
      filter: {
        bool: {
          should: {
            term: { published: true }
          }
        }
      }
    )
  end
end
```

Do you guys tried this before?
Can someone give me a hand on that?

Cheers

Comment: i am not good with ruby on rails but I think you are not doing right,
You can use elasticsearch api to filter , and for source filtering too ..
http://rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/

Comment: The best way to debug elastic search is to use Sense, it's part of marvel.  You'll have a much easier time generating the raw json query and then you can figure out how to generate it with the rails gem.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure, but it seems to me that you have an ES syntactic error.

Could you please past the JSon sent through the ES request?

I guess that your JSon should look like this:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "published": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But you send this:

```
{
  "only" : [ "valueForId", "valueForTitle", "isPublished" ],
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "published": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note: to more accurate answers regarding ES, inform the version of the tools you are using (ES 1.0.1 for example) and the data (the content of the JSon) sent to the ES Server, because ES had a quite important syntactic change in the past months and sometimes it is hard to figure out what your class is doing or what you have in your params (:id, :title ...).